# Can you explain the following Octave/MatLab code for me?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

```
load train.txt train(186,:)=[]; 
train = train(:,[1 2 4]); 
load test.txt test = test(:,[1 2 4]); 
p1 = clrscr(test(:,1), bayes_cls(train, test(:,2:end), @classpdf_indep, 0.1)); 
p1 = [p1 clserr(test(:,1), bayes_cls(train, test(:,2:end), @classpdf_dep, 0.1))]; 
p1 = [p1 clserr(test(:,1), bayes_cls(train, test(:,2:end), @classpdf_parzen, 0.1))]
```

1. a text file named `train.txt` is loaded into octave as a matrix. And, we are selecting 186 rows from that matrix. Then what is happening with `=[]`?
2. we are selecting all the rows from the matrix `train` with columns 1,2 and 4 only and assigning that to the old matrix. In essence we are purging some data. Am I right?
3. we are loading `test.txt` into octave and selecting all the rows of columns 1,2 and 4. Am I right?

then, what is going on with the lines # 4,5 and 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should ask your instructer who wrote the code? Nevertheless:

1. There is a matrix "train" saved in the file train.txt. It's loaded and the 186. row is deleted.
2. you are right
3. you are right but I think you've made a copy and paste error and missed a ";" and linebreak
4. it's hard to say without knowing if clscr, clserr, bayes_cls are functions or arrays (I guess they are functions, in this case it's a call to clrscr with first column of test, a call to bayes and so on) and the result is filled into p1

I'm bailing out at this point. These are all basic funtions/methods and you should learn the basic concepts of the matlab language. This is like asking "please explain y = f(x) = sin(x) + x^3"